# Difference between Convert.ToByte(val) and (byte)val

Tags: c#, .net

As said in the title I don't understand the difference between this two type of conversion. Not only for the byte but also the other variable type.

So what is the difference and when I have to use one instead of the other?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: What a fast reply! Thank you very much!

Comment: The answer really depends on the type of `val`. You can check the mono [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/5a20d0438a420272b44f9a52baf74429e3de8de6/mcs/class/corlib/System/Convert.cs#L405) or download [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to see how it works.